# How to group by when querying duplicate records?

Tags: mysql, duplication

I have a table with duplicates and I want to present it to the stakeholders so they can help me determine the source of duplication.  Currently I can print 1 row for each duplicate entry, but I want to show all attributes for each.  Here's the query I'm using:

```
select *, count(*), max(id) from foos group by name having count(*) > 1 order by name;
```

I'm not sure how to alter the query to get each record where another record shares a name.  Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  foos 
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT
      name
    FROM 
      foos 
    GROUP BY 
      name 
    HAVING 
      COUNT(*) > 1 
  ) AS dup
  ON foos.name = dup.name
ORDER BY 
  name
```